# When I zoom in the browser, the document.body.clientWidth changed

Tags: html, css, viewport

Suppose I adjust my browser window to `1000px`, then I print the viewport width:

```
 document.body.clientWidth // 1000
```

then I zoom in my browser, which set it as 150% larger， then I print the viewport width again:

```
document.body.clientWidth // 667
```

Why it become narrow? What's more important is how the number `667` computed out? It seems narrow 1/3;

Comment: 1000/150*100 equals what …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it 1000/150*100? 
The size of browser window (the browser viewport, NOT including toolbars and scrollbars).

ClientWith only works in IE5-8 by the way. You could you use window.innerWidth for other modern browsers and above IE8